# Grails GORM multiple hasMany of same type?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is it possible to have a domain class that multiple hasMany relationships of the same type where the objects are kept in separate tables?

```
class Child {
    String description
    static belongsTo = [parent: Parent]
}

class Parent {
    static hasMany = [childAssociation1 : Child, childAssociation2 : Child]
}
```

When I create a child object and add to one of the parent hasMany associations then query it from the other, it appears in both.

i.e. when I add using:

```
parent.addToChildAssociation1(child)
```

then child is a member of parent.addToChildAssociation2

Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: It's because of your belongsTo. This is expected behavior because it satisfies the relationship through both associations. Either remove the belongsTo or model your collection/associations with a correct model between the association and the person.